# Prismjs not highlighting typescript code snippets

Tags: javascript, typescript, prismjs

I was toying around with Prism.js and for some reason, highlighting `typescript` code is not working as intended. Prism.js couldn't event tokenize the snippet...

*[Here is a demo within codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/prismjs-tester-forked-nk4sss?file=/src/index.js)*

Any help/idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When imported as a module, Prism by default does not include all languages (otherwise the bundle would be very large). Prism only includes the common/popular/most used languages like HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and even Markdown.

To add TypeScript, you have to import the component like this:

```
import Prism from "prismjs";
import "prismjs/themes/prism-twilight.css";
import "prismjs/components/prism-typescript";
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/prismjs-tester-forked-8i5910)